# Dictionaries into dictionary python 3.7 windows

Tags: python

How could I get this in the programm below?:

```
dict_cars {1 : {'Mercedes':'E500'}},{ 2 : {'Ford' : 'Focus'}},{ 3 {'Toyota' : 'Celica'}}
```

My current programm is not working and I don't know how to fix it :(

```
dict_cars = {}
attributes = {}

car_number = input ('Insert car number: ')
car_brand = input ('Insert car brand: ')
car_model = input ('Insert car model: ')


while car_number != 'end':

    dict_cars[car_number] = attributes
    dict_cars[car_number][car_brand] = car_model

    car_number = input ('Insert car number: ')
    car_brand = input ('Insert car brand: ')
    car_model = input ('Insert car model: ')
```

Instead what I want, I get:

```
Insert car number: 1
Insert car brand: Mercedes
Insert car model: E500
Insert car number: 2
Insert car brand: Ford
Insert car model: Focus
Insert car number: 3
Insert car brand: Toyota
Insert car model: Celica
Insert car number: end
Insert car brand: 
Insert car model: 
>>> dict_cars
{'1': {'Mercedes': 'E500', 'Ford': 'Focus', 'Toyota': 'Celica'}, '2'{'Mercedes': 'E500', 'Ford': 'Focus', 'Toyota': 'Celica'}, '3': {'Mercedes': 
'E500', 'Ford': 'Focus', 'Toyota': 'Celica'}}
```

Comment: If your car number is always in a similar ascending order you might want to consider a list of dictionaries instead of a dictionary of dictionaries. It makes indexing simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you keep reusing the `attributes` dictionary, and since you never remove anything from it, it contains all of the previous car information.

Try this instead:

```
dict_cars = {}

while True:
    car_number = input ('Insert car number: ')

    if car_number == 'end':
        break

    car_brand = input ('Insert car brand: ')
    car_model = input ('Insert car model: ')

    dict_cars[car_number] = {car_brand: car_model}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was reusing the `attributes` dictionary to represent what you expected to be an empty dictionary. Effectively each dictionary kept referencing that old memory location which you had already written to. A fix would be to exclude that dictionary from your code and just use a blank one instead

```
dict_cars = {}

car_number = input ('Insert car number: ')
car_brand = input ('Insert car brand: ')
car_model = input ('Insert car model: ')


while car_number != 'end':

    dict_cars[car_number] = {}
    dict_cars[car_number][car_brand] = car_model

    car_number = input ('Insert car number: ')
    car_brand = input ('Insert car brand: ')
    car_model = input ('Insert car model: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_cars = {}

while True:
    car_number=0
    car_brand=""
    car_model=""
    car_number = input ('Insert car number: ')
    if car_number=='end':
        break
    car_brand = input ('Insert car brand: ')
    car_model = input ('Insert car model: ')
    dict_cars[car_number] ={}
    dict_cars[car_number][car_brand] = car_model  

print(dict_cars)
```

The above code gives you required output.

```
{1 : {'Mercedes':'E500'}},{ 2 : {'Ford' : 'Focus'}},{ 3 {'Toyota' : 'Celica'}}
```